# How to select records without duplicate on just one field in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, distinct

I have a table with 3 columns like this:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+  
| Country_id | country_title | State |  
+------------+---------------+-------+
```

There are many records in this table. Some of them have `state` and some other don't. Now, imagine these records:

```
1 | Canada  | Alberta  
2 |  Canada | British  Columbia  
3 | Canada  | Manitoba  
4 | China   |
```

I need to have country names without any duplicate. Actually I need their `id` and `title`, What is the best SQL command to make this? I used `DISTINCT` in the form below but I could not achieve an appropriate result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT title,id FROM tbl_countries ORDER BY title
```

My desired result is something like this:

```
1, Canada  
4, China
```

Comment: What result did you get from the query you tried, and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: I'm getting a result set with many records containing Canada.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? Can you show what your desired result set is. Make it explicit. By that I mean don't just describe what you want in your own words. Update your question showing the *exact* results you get and the *exact* results you want, in tabular format, and in a clear and precise way.

Comment: You write "Actually I need their id and title" (i.e two columns) but in your edit the  desired result only has one column. Please explain this discrepancy.

Comment: It was my mistake, sorry for it. I will edit it

Comment: So you want the minimum ID for each country, right?

Comment: @MarkByers I need to prevent duplicated records on country name. I mean I don't like to show the second Canada when I had 1 before.

Comment: Badly worded question - you give one set of column headings at top - then proceed to use another set in the SQL.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, title
FROM tbl_countries
GROUP BY title
```

Answer (score 52):

`DISTINCT` is the keyword
For me your query is correct

Just try to do this first

```
SELECT DISTINCT title,id FROM tbl_countries
```

Later on you can try with order by.

Comment: Results of query will just remove `State` column, And it's not that the OP needs ;).

Comment: This only makes sure that each resulting tuple from the query is unique, not that each value in a column is unique.

Answer (score 19):

For using `DISTINCT` keyword, you can use it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (SELECT min(ti.Country_id) 
     FROM tbl_countries ti 
     WHERE t.country_title = ti.country_title) As Country_id
    , country_title
FROM 
    tbl_countries t
```

---

For using `ROW_NUMBER()`, you can use it like this:

```
SELECT 
    Country_id, country_title 
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_title ORDER BY Country_id) As rn
    FROM tbl_countries) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

Also with using `LEFT JOIN`, you can use this:

```
SELECT t1.Country_id, t1.country_title
FROM tbl_countries t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tbl_countries t2 ON t1.country_title = t2.country_title AND t1.Country_id > t2.Country_id
WHERE
    t2.country_title IS NULL
```

---

And with using of `EXISTS`, you can try:

```
SELECT t1.Country_id, t1.country_title
FROM tbl_countries t1   
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM tbl_countries t2 
                WHERE t1.country_title = t2.country_title AND t1.Country_id > t2.Country_id)
```

Comment: can this be used to select all data in a row? As all the examples im finding have the columns set and when i run it with select * it doesnt work. Not sure whether to pursue troubleshooting if these solutions wont work for Select *

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
SELECT country_id, country_title 
FROM (SELECT country_id, country_title,
CASE
WHEN country_title=LAG(country_title, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY country_title) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS "Duplicates"
FROM tbl_countries)
WHERE "Duplicates"=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL a special column function `GROUP_CONCAT` can be used:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'computers' AND
    TABLE_NAME='Laptop' AND
    COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('code')
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

It should be mentioned that the information schema in MySQL covers all database server, not certain databases. That is why if different databases contains tables with identical `names, search` condition of the `WHERE` clause should specify the schema name: `TABLE_SCHEMA='computers'`.

Strings are concatenated with the `CONCAT` function in MySQL. The final solution of our problem can be expressed in MySQL as:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='computers' AND
    TABLE_NAME='Laptop' AND
        COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('code')
 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
), ' FROM Laptop');
```

http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select20.php

Answer (score 1):

```
select Country_id,country_title from(
   select Country_id,country_title,row_number() over (partition by country_title 
   order by Country_id  ) rn from country)a
   where rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore duplicate rows in SQL. I think this may help you.

```
    SELECT res2.*
    FROM
    (SELECT res1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY res1.title ORDER BY res1.id)as num
     FROM 
    (select * from [dbo].[tbl_countries])as res1
    )as res2
    WHERE res2.num=1
```

Answer (score -2):

`Having` Clause is the easiest way to find duplicate entry in Oracle and using `rowid` we can remove duplicate data..

```sql
DELETE FROM products WHERE rowid IN (
  SELECT MAX(sl) FROM (
  SELECT itemcode, (rowid) sl FROM products WHERE itemcode IN (
  SELECT itemcode FROM products GROUP BY itemcode HAVING COUNT(itemcode)>1
)) GROUP BY itemcode);
```

Comment: Not a good idea to tell people to delete their data when they only want to view it.