# How to select records without duplicate

Tags: mysql

Hi all i have smal problem with sql i just need the result without duplicate
SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `charts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timespan` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visits` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

SQl Insert:

```
INSERT INTO charts (timespan, visits)
VALUES "2016-02-14 10:00 PM", '1234')";
```

Result:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM charts");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['timespan'] . "\t" . $row['visits']. "\n";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select records without duplicate on just one field in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239169/how-to-select-records-without-duplicate-on-just-one-field-in-sql)

Comment: Seriously, did you [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+select+distinct) this?

Comment: You need all the **distinct** rows? Or rows with distinct values on a single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only distinct rows, you can use the `distinct` keyword:

```
select distinct * from charts
```

However, if you need distinct values for a single column, you need to use a `group by` in your clause, depending what column needs distinct values and agregate the other ones.

Comment: yes i know my problem is INSERT INTO charts (timespan, visits)
VALUES "2016-02-14 10:00 PM", '1234')"; so if hit 10 time it will add to my sql table so i want no duplicate of the visits = 1234 exemple if in the insert the visits  = 1234 then dont need to added is just neet function to check if the visits is already in the database

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you very well. If you ant distinct data, just as I said in answer.
... You can also use `select avg(timespan), visits from charts group by visits`

Comment: @Tim, I am glad I could help you.