# SQL aggregate using DISTINCT on ID by latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

**Request**
I have a section of data below and my goal is to limit the agent column to be distinct only containing unique values, where the unique value selected is the latest date it was modified.

**Existing Data**

```
modified     agent  rank 
2016-10-18  346502  0   
2013-06-04  346502  41  
2011-10-31  346503  0   
2012-08-13  346505  0   
2016-04-18  346506  66  
2015-01-27  346506  1   
2016-01-21  346507  103 
2015-01-27  346507  130 
2012-01-30  346508  0
```

Trying to use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29912858/461887 as a basis but cannot get where to aggregate it properly.

**SQL not working**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time
  ,FLiex.agtprof.agent_id
  ,FLiex.agtprof.rank
  ,FLiex.agtprof.external_id
WHERE
    FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time = MAX( FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time)
FROM
  FLiex.agtprof
```

**Desired Output**

```
modify  agent   rank
18/10/2016  346502  0
18/04/2016  346506  66
21/01/2016  346507  103
13/08/2012  346505  0
30/01/2012  346508  0
31/10/2011  346503  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to get single row data, but based on the other rows. While this may be possible with aggregate functions, it's much easier to do with window (analytic) functions:

```
SELECT [modified], [agent], [rank], [id]
FROM   (SELECT [modified], [agent], [rank], [id],
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [agent]
                                  ORDER BY [modified] DESC) AS rn
        FROM   [agtprof]) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: This looks the best solution however I could not get the second From [table]) t to work. It returns invalid object name. I have voted up yours as I need to learn more about it and also voted up the one from @Laughing Vergil I got working

Comment: SELECT [FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time], [,FLiex.agtprof.agent_id], [,FLiex.agtprof.rank], [,FLiex.agtprof.external_id]
FROM   (SELECT [FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time], [,FLiex.agtprof.agent_id], [,FLiex.agtprof.rank],  [,FLiex.agtprof.external_id],
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  [,FLiex.agtprof.agent_id]
                                  ORDER BY [FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time] DESC) AS rn
        FROM   [FLiex.agtprof]) t
WHERE  rn = 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT max(id_date), agent, rank, id
FROM fliex.agtprof
GROUP BY 2,3,4;
```

Try this.  I think if you chose the max id_date and then group by the rest, you should get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time
    ,FLiex.agtprof.agent_id
    ,FLiex.agtprof.rank
    ,FLiex.agtprof.external_id
FROM
    FLiex.agtprof
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        Max(FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time) as max_mod_date_time
        ,FLiex.agtprof.agent_id as agent_id
    FROM
        FLiex.agtprof
    GROUP BY FLiex.agtprof.agent_id
    ) Filter
    ON FLiex.agtprof.agentID = Filter.agent_id
    AND FLiex.agtprof.modify_date_time = Filter.max_mod_date_time
```