# Trying to use mysql to exclude certain ones

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to mySQL.  I have a table that is supposed to be mutually exclusive between fields labeled "b" or "s", but they aren't.  Some fields in column tn have "b", and another field has "s" but they both have the same "tn". This is a data issue I'm waiting for someone to fix.  In the meantime, I need to exclude from my "b" query, any items where "tn" would also be in the similar "s" query.  My query just has the "b" ones in it, how do I compare against the "s" ones and exclude the crossover errors?  Also, I want to exclude any "b" ones with a "tn" count over 2.  I know they need to fix the data, but while I'm waiting the months that will take, I want to get a set of data to start with, that is clean.  I need the returned row to include all columns shown.

The Table hardware_data looks like this:

```
tn         hardware_item   shelf   slot   port   type   model
12345678   abcdefg         1       1      1      b     Model1
23456789   bcdefgh         1       2      3      b     Model1
23456789   bcdefgh         1       2      3      s     Model1
34567890   cdefghi         1       1      4      s     Model1
12345678   abcdefg         1       1      4      b     Model1
12345678   abcdefg         1       1      3      b     Model1
45678901   defghij         1       1      2      b     Model1
45678901   defghij         1       1      3      b     Model1
```

So in the above data, I would use the following query:

```
select hardware_item, tn, shelf, slot, port
from accessInventory.hardware_data
WHERE model= 'Model1'
AND type = 'b'
AND CHAR_LENGTH(tn)>3
AND tn*1 = tn
LIMIT 100000;
```

And it returns this data set

```
tn         hardware_item  shelf  slot  port  type    model
45678901   defghij        1       1       2    b     Model1
45678901   defghij        1       1       3    b     Model1
23456789   bcdefgh        1       2       3    b     Model1
12345678   abcdefg        1       1       4    b     Model1
12345678   abcdefg        1       1       3    b     Model1
12345678   abcdefg        1       1       1    b     Model1
```

But I want it to exclude the ones with a duplicate count "tn" over 2 like 12345678  , and ones that cross-over with the "s" category, like 23456789.  I don't even know where to start with the cross-over one, and my count over 3 exclusion isn't working because it's comparing the entire row returned and not just the "tn".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've googled it of course, but I'm not finding anything for the exclusion I need, and I haven't found this specific case for excluding ones where count of common row items exceeds a value.

Note, can't use "Group By" because it's valid to have 2 tn's matching in "b" category.

Comment: I found this that can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239169/how-to-select-records-without-duplicate-on-just-one-field-in-sql

Comment: "And it returns this data set ..." - I don't believe.. With `Group BY tn` you should not get any duplicates in `tn` column.

Comment: Yes it does...  Here's a segment of my data returned, showing duplicate tn's.  I think it's because the shelf/slot/port are considered in the duplicate category. hardware   tn   shelf   slot   port   c   CITRFLBLCKDC 105100 1 2 21 2
CITRFLLKM1DC 105101 1 1 21 2
CITRFLSTORDC 105101 2 1 1 2
CITRFLBASRDC 105101 2 2 7 2

Comment: Actually, I think you're right because I had to doctor the tn's so I don't post things I shouldn't online.  I looked at it again.  And I shouldn't be using Group By, because it's valid to have 2 tn's same in the "b" category.

Comment: @Zyigh - I can't use Group By because it's valid to have 2 tn's the same in "b" category.  I removed it from the query.  I'm still trying to get rid of any tn's where tn>3, and tn's that are also in the "s" category from my "b" query.