# How do you remove duplicate rows of primary key and also group by in SQL Bigquery?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, duplicates, grouping

SQL BigQuery - I have duplicate rows on the primary key that I need to remove (I don't want to permanently delete from the table). I have to GROUP BY several other fields to aggregate results, and am having issues since I have to include the primary key but cannot group by it and remove duplicates at the same time.

I saw examples on stack but am having issues applying to this case. I have tried the below, and that is not resulting in any groupings because I have to group by the ID to leave it in the select statement.

```
SELECT Distinct (ID),Event_ID,Event_Name,Sum(Quantity), Sum(Price*Quantity)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, Event_ID, Event_Name
```

I tried removing ID from the group by clause and adding "Min (Distinct (ID))," as the first select line, but that was not removing the duplicates.

I also tried

```
SELECT Distinct (ID),Event_ID, Event_Name, Sum(Quantity) ,Sum(Price*Quantity), 
FROM table

INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT ID as DeduplicatedID
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY ID) deduplicatedtable ON table.ID = deduplicatedtable.ID

GROUP BY ID, Event_ID, Event_Name
```

and  [received this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJGTA.png)

Thanks in advance!

[image: Here is a screenshot]

of the group at the ID level, however some of these IDs have duplicates, which provide incorrect TotalQuantity and TotalRevenue numbers when grouped by the Event

[image: Here is a picture]

of what I would want the grouped data to look like, but this is incorrect and includes the duplicate IDs when the quantity and rev fields are summed.

Comment: Primary keys -- by definition -- do not have duplicates.  Please explain what column or columns should not be duplicated.  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: correct - I guess it is supposed to be the primary key but for some reason there are duplicates of certain rows and I can't parse out a rhyme or reason why it is only some rows and not others...I am adding screenshots of data now to Original post

Comment: added the pictures above

Comment: What exactly is duplicated? The the entire row or only the id value? I mean, for the duplicated ID value, the rest of the row is similar or different?

Comment: There are several answers to do this in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239169/how-to-select-records-without-duplicate-on-just-one-field-in-sql), including Gordon's. Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29912858/11928117)

Comment: @rmesteves the entire row is duplicated

Comment: If the entire row is duplicated then both of the below answers should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as id, Event_ID,Event_Name,Sum(Quantity), Sum(Price*Quantity)
FROM table
GROUP BY Event_ID, Event_Name
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not get rid of the duplicates for me; unsure why exactly

Comment: to add, when I run this, it is getting rid of all of the other IDs that are not duplicates and that are not the min ID

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
WITH t as (
SELECT Distinct *
FROM table
)
SELECT ID, Event_ID, Event_Name, Sum(Quantity), Sum(Price*Quantity)
FROM t
GROUP BY ID, Event_ID, Event_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as I suspect, there is one field that is not duplicated, find it and use `ANY_VALUE(not_duplicated_field)`.
 The [ANY_VALUE function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#any_value) returns any value from the input or NULL if there are zero input rows. The value returned is non-deterministic, which means you might receive a different result each time you use this function.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Event_ID, ANY_VALUE(Event_Name), sum(Quantity), sum(Price*Quantity)
FROM blabla.jack
GROUP BY id, Event_ID
```